# How do I restore a whole bucket of archived objects in Oracle cloud?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, cloud-object-storage, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have an object storage bucket on Oracle cloud, which contains a large number of archived objects. I want to restore all of them for download.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/managingobjects_topic-To_restore_objects_from_Archive_Storage.htm#:%7E:text=To%20restore%20a%20single%20object,Available%20for%20Download%20in%20Hours.), I am able to select and restore individual objects via the web interface, but this would be very cumbersome to do for more than a few.

My current "best" attempt is to use the OCI CLI to list all the objects in the bucket, grep the names, and then to use a BASH script to loop through them all sending restore requests. This however, still seems very slow, and is taking many hours.

Surely there is a better way to do this. Is there no way simply to bulk restore an entire bucket? I can't find anything in the Oracle documentation that would let me do this.